# how to create treeview having checkboxes in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

how to create treeview having checkboxes in asp.net mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [dynatree](http://www.guyellisrocks.com/2009/08/aspnet-mvc-with-jquery-dynatree-plugin.html) replaced by [Fancytreee](http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/demo/#sample-select.html)

Answer (score 1):

ExtJS treeview can do that; just use the script in one of your views.

http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/tree/check-tree.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also you a native ASP.NET TreeView that supports checkboxes such as ComponentArt's http://www.componentart.com/products/aspnetmvc/, or Telerik's, http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/treeview.aspx#checkbox-and-tristate-checkboxes-support.